# Question about (topological) orientation of an $n$-dimensional manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This comes from Hatcher's textbook on page 234.

Let $H_n(X|A)=H_n(X,X-A)$.

He defines an orientation of an $n$-manifold $M$ to be a function $x \mapsto \mu_x$ assigning to each $x \in M$ a local orientation $\mu_x \in H_n(M|x)$ satisfying the "local consistency condition" that each $x \in M$ has a neighborhood $\mathbb{R}^n \subset M$ containing an open ball $B$ of finite radius about $x$ such that all the local orientations $\mu_y$ at points $y \in B$ are the images of one generator $\mu_B$ of $H_n(M|B) \approx H_n(\mathbb{R}^n |B)$ under the natural maps $H_n(M|B) \rightarrow H_n(M|y)$.

> What are these so called natural maps $H_n(M|B) \rightarrow H_n(M|y)$?

Comment: The inclusion $M\setminus B\hookrightarrow M\setminus\{y\}$ gives a map of space pairs $(M,M\setminus B)\to(M,M\setminus\{y\})$. This induces a map in relative homology.

Comment: Is this necessary to be an isomorphism ?

Comment: Yes, since the map $M \to M$ is a homotopy equivalence and the map $M \setminus B \to M \setminus \{y\}$ is a homotopy equivalence, and you have the relative homology long exact sequence.

Comment: @MikeMiller Can you give more details? I don't see why this is a homotopy equivalence.